# Flutter - any issues with making top level MyApp widget stateful?

Tags: flutter

I'm looking at using the 'Once' package to support the launching of daily tasks. (see https://pub.dev/packages/once)

This package seems to require that the top level 'MyApp' widget be set as a Stateful Widget. In the past all my Flutter projects have used a stateless MyApp widget. Are there any issues with making this change I should be aware of?

Comment: No.  No problems at all.  Why would you think that?

Comment: Not sure - there is a general sense from various sources that stateful widgets are best avoided.   I'm a big RiverPod user, so for most cases all of my widgets are stateless

Comment: A stateful widget introduces some additional boilerplate because you are creating two classes instead of one, but most IDEs automate even that.  Otherwise, use Stateful when you need local state... no worries!